# std::this_thread::yield() usage?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, c++11

Can someone provide real-life example of `std::this_thread::yield()` usage in c++ application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used yield in the implementation of std::lock, found here:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/mutex

It turns out that when locking multiple locks/mutexes at a time, when you fail to get one, you can make the application *faster* by using yield prior to trying the locks/mutexes in a different order.

In this source code I'm actually calling `sched_yield()`.  But that is only for the purpose of getting the header dependency the way I wanted it.  On this platform `std::this_thread::yield()` is nothing more than a call to `sched_yield()`:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/thread