# How to use std::this_thread::yield() deterministically?

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, c++11, scheduling

While developing a VoIP based application, we have a common multi-threaded C++11 module.
It works fine in iOS, MacOS but finds thread scheduling difficulty in Android.

### Optional Design Description (only if interested)

I have few threads running with message queues.

1. Master  (writes data to sockets which is received in SSL_Read queue)
2. SSL_Read (reads data from SSL and updates in its queue)
3. SSL_Write (writes data to SSL which is received directly from Socket threads)
4. Thread per Socket (reads data from socket and send to SSL_Write queue)

1-2 are related and 3-4 are related.
I have observed that during many calls, only 2 threads are actively running and other 2 threads don't get running time. Due to which 1 way voice path is observed.

### Problem

I doubted this as an Android Linux issue and for that, I have an unanswered post already:
[c++11 multithreading issues with Android where some threads are not scheduled properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439183/c11-multithreading-issues-with-android-where-some-threads-are-not-scheduled-pr).
Went through [std::this_thread::yield() usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604059/stdthis-threadyield-usage)

The goal is to give similar time slicing to all threads. Tried following options:

1. I decided to use `std::thread::yield()` when the message queue is
   filled up beyond certain limit; e.g. 10 messages from 1 thread. I
   tried `yield()` 1 time and 100 time in loop, but there is no
   advantage of it. The same thread continue running.
2. Same thing for `sleep_for()` option with 0 and 100 ms. Same thread keep running.
3. Tried changing `nice()` value to -10, -20 for all threads but no
   luck.

How to use `std::this_thread::yield()` effectively without burning out too many CPU cycles?

Comment: Why are you using yield() instead of normal inter-thread comms mechanisms like condvars/semaphores?

Comment: @MartinJames, the `std::mutex` with `notify_all()` is already used. Despite that I am seeing such behavior every alternate time.

Answer (score 5):

It is legal for `std::this_thread::yield()` to do absolutely nothing. It provides an opportunity for the scheduler to schedule another thread; the scheduler doesn't have to take advantage of it.

You could try either:

1. Having each thread able to process whatever work needs doing, by packaging the work into a generic task queue. That way it doesn't matter which thread takes the work, the most important work gets done when there is a thread to do it.
2. Adding synchronization between the threads such as a barrier mechanism (see e.g. boost's barrier class) to keep all 4 threads in sync.